# Clear toggle() on different screen size

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, toggle

I have a link that I want to reveal more content on click, but only on mobile screen. I am using resize and load function to determine the screen size, however when I resize to small screen then to big screen and I click the link it still toggles, its like this unbind doesn't completely work, or sometimes it also affects the links on small screen and they stop working at all:

fiddle here: resize your screen to test:
http://jsfiddle.net/mp429cp5/1/

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {    
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
        $('ul').hide();         
            $('a').bind( "click", function() {
                $('ul').toggle();
                $('ul').toggleClass('collapsed');
                return false;
            });
} else if ($(window).width() > 960) {
        $('a').click(function(){
            $('ul').unbind('click').toggle();
        });             
     }              
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put the if screen size inside of the click handler so if the screen is bigger than 960, execute. This way you avoid the unbind that you are trying to do and this code does not run every time you resize.

For the `ul` hiding/showing, this can be done in CSS with media queries

http://jsfiddle.net/mp429cp5/5/

also you might want to do a .show() for the ul when width > 960

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 960) {
            $('ul').hide();
        } else {
            $('ul').show();
        }
    });

    $('a').bind("click", function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 960) {
            $('ul').toggle();
            $('ul').toggleClass('collapsed');
        }
        return false;
    });
});

$(window).on("load", function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
        $('ul').hide();
    } else {
        $('ul').show();
    }
});
```

You should actually make the current content of resize and load into a fucntion and just call it. I just copied it to show you what I meant

Comment: I applied your solution, it improved it a bit, at elast it doesn't show the 'ul' on large screen anymore, however:  if I resize to full width and click on a link, and then resize to small the toggle doesn't work, I have to resize again and then it works again. I made the 'ul' to hide in both cases.

Comment: @yennefer I don't know what issues you are having. I just tried it on the fiddle and it works perfectly. Make a fiddle to demonstrate your issue because if you used my code directly then it should work

Comment: should `$(window).on("load resize"` be inside `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`, outside or does it not matter?

Comment: @yennefer actually you should separate them. The on load can be outside since on load runs after document ready and the resize can be either inside of doc ready or in on load. I am going to update the answer so they are not together

Comment: maybe I should just ditch the toggle all together? it causes a lot of issues. I've put the log inside my conditionals and they work perfect, but If I resize a lot the link with toggle doesn't work. I have no idea why. and its quite random. What could I use instead of toggle? or maybe there is other issue of clearing queue or something?

Comment: @yennefer You could just do show and hide instead of toggle but I don't think that's where the issue is. No matter how much you resize, it should not affect the click since you can't resize and click at the same time. Again, I have to see your code to debug the issue you are having

Comment: why your `bind("click")` thing is outside any on.load or on.resize?  I've put mine actually inside the resize / load function to constantly check the winodw size - could that be the problem?

Comment: @yennefer there is a comment that says put this in doc ready, I will edit it so you understand better. The click handler and resize handler are inside of doc ready

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working fine now, I'm starting from scratch (I had more of those functions there). I was constantly putting the click handler inside the 'resize' function, like in my first post, I thought if I use the conditional based on width I have to put it inside 'resize' function?

Comment: @yennefer Sorry was the last sentence a question? Can you clarify it I didn't get it

Comment: :) your `$('a').bind("click", function ()` is outside `$(window).on("resize", function () {` . And I thought that whenever I use `if ($(window).width() < 960) {` I have to put the whole condition into that `$(window).on("resize", function () {` so I was placing my `bind("click"` inside there too - which I think was causing issue. Although I still do not understand why it is outside and still finds the width?

Comment: @yennefer because `if ($(window).width() < 960)` checks the width at the time of the click. The handler runs the code at the time you click, so it will get the window width of the time you clicked. Do you fully understand this now? The resize function runs when the window is resized. The click handler runs when it is called (when you click)

Comment: Hence the reordering of the 'if' statement - It completely makes sense now, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use `window.screen.availHeight` and `window.screen.availWidth` to determine the screen size.

You may also wish to test for events specific to touch devices (eg. `window.ontouch`).

Comment: `window.screen.availWidth` returns screen width not browser width

Comment: @huangism The op expressly writes about _screen width_, so your comment and your downvote seem to be rather unjustified.

Comment: If you read the code, you can see what the OP is trying to achieve

Comment: @huangism if you read _the text_ you can see what the op is trying to achieve. If you read the code you see how it fails to do so.

Comment: Oh yes OP said screen size, and you thought it was actual screen size. I can see where you made the mistake. After all it's so easy to resize screen size and people do it all the time. Anyway, I guess the OP choosing my answer as the right one is also a mistake, you should definitely let the OP know that he/she made a mistake.

Comment: @Huangism Yes, in fact people do resize their screen all the time, it just takes some cable to connect to the display hardware of their choice or some software to mirror their handheld screens. Anyway, the op's answer choice made clear what he wanted, so everybody is fine and you get an A+ in divination.

Comment: No people don't resize their screens all the time, developers might be doing a lot but normal people who surfs the net don't. It seems every one is fine except for you

Comment: @Huangism You've been absent from enterprise settings for quite some time, haven't you? Some may argue that (non-developing) company folk and their use cases (eg. doing presentations) aren't 'normal' by whatever standard they presuppose but, frankly, this discussion has strayed far from the subject of the question into the absurd.

Comment: Yes doing presentations of a webpage that runs in a browser.

Comment: @Huangism Indeed, there are even companies making money with software tools to do so. However, back on topic, the wording of the op's hint to his fiddle should have given me the clue that he didn't talk of hw specs. Admitting this to the more diligent though unimaginative Huangism hopefully allows for this ridiculous chat to r.i.p.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing about you just delete the answer since it doesn't contribute to the question